# Kickstart partitioning with ext4 in autopart mode?

Tags: centos6, partition, ext4, kickstart

When installing CentOS 6.x, how to specify the filesystem type with ext4 and also use the autopart directive in kickstart file?

The default filesystem type with autopart directive used is ext3, which can not manage a very large disk space.

Answer (score 2):

The filesystem type isn't an option for `autopart`, unfortunately. The only options `autopart` supports is regarding encryption. It looks like you'll have to switch to using `part` to define the partitions.

From the documentation:

> Note that the **autopart** option cannot be used together with the **part/partition**, **raid**, **logvol**, or **volgroup** options in the same kickstart file.

You might be interested in reading more about the [Kickstart Options](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html) here.

Comment: I actually could not find a solution in the document then i asked a question here. Thank you all the same.

Comment: Right, cause the document shows it isn't possible with existing options. The document is more for moving toward manually setting up your partitions.